# Can Maven 'import' resource dependencies?

Tags: maven, resources, maven-resources-plugin

Across several projects I have some *resources* (specifically Flyway database migration scripts) that I'd like to be shared.

Is it possible to have these shared resources exist as a Maven artifact, and prior to a build have Maven resolve that dependency and unpack the contents of the artifact to `/src/main/resources/`? If so, how would one go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you place some files in `/src/main/resources` they will be placed on the CLASSPATH in the target JAR artifact. This means if you depend on such an artifact, you will have access to all resources, just as you have access to classes in it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-resources</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If `my-resources` artifact contains some resources in `/src/main/resources`, you can access them **at runtime** just like you (or any other library) can access `/src/main/resources` contents from the same artifact.

Note that this won't work with `/src/test/resources` because test resources are only placed on CLASSPATH during `surefire` execution of current artifact.

Comment: Thanks! Would the same work for `/src/test/resources` if the dependency scope was `test`?

Comment: @Deejay: no. Also you cannot import classes from `/src/test/java`, even when imported using `test` scope.

Comment: You can simply put the resources in your `test` artitact's `src/main/resources`.

Comment: @carlspring: I was wondering if the resources from the artifact could end up in `/src/test/resources/`, as I have use cases where said resources are only needed for setting up JUnit tests.

Comment: @Deejay should work by following http://stackoverflow.com/a/12299238/1266906 in the sence of classpaths

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz When importing a dependency of Project B in Project A, how can we STOP importing all the resources of Project B in A.